# Does Euler-Lagrange extremization of $L=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ lead to the Maxwell equations?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, electromagnetism

Suppose $F_{\mu\nu}$ and $F^{\mu\nu}$ are defined as follows:

$$F_{\mu\nu} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & E_x & E_y & E_z \\ -E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\ -E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\ -E_z & -B_y & B_z & 0\end{bmatrix}, F^{\mu\nu} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -E_x & -E_y & -E_z \\ E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\ E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\ E_z & -B_y & B_z & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

We define $L_{Maxwell}$ to be:

$$L = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{4}(-2E_x^2-2E_y^2-2E_z^2+2B_x^2+2B_y^2+2B_z^2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(E_x^2 + E_y^2 + E_z^2 - B_x^2 - B_y^2 - B_z^2)$$

Extremizing for $L_{\vec A + \vec \epsilon} - L_{\vec A}$, we obtain the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$ \color{blue}{E_x + E_y + E_z - B_x - B_y - B_z  = 0}$$

Would this be the correct form of the Euler-Lagrange equation for L?

I can't exactly see how the above solution is equivalent to Maxwell's equations in free space?

$$\nabla \cdot \vec E = 0$$
$$\nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$$
$$\nabla \times \vec E = -\frac{\partial\vec B}{\partial t}$$
$$\nabla \times \vec B = \frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}$$

Comment: Your Euler-Lagrange equation has no differentiation in $E$ and $B$ and thus is wrong. What do you mean by Extremizing here? Without showing any work, it is impossible to tell what went wrong.

Comment: First of all, I suppose the functional is $\int_{\mathbb R^4} (-\frac 14 F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu})$ right? Where's the integration?

Comment: I honestly don't understand your calculations. You lost me at the first equality. Why is there no differentiation of $\epsilon$ on the right hand side?

Comment: I suggest you start with something simpler. Say consider the functional $E(f)= \frac 12\int_{\mathbb R}  (f')^2$. (where $f$ are just functions on $\mathbb R$) Can you derive the Euler-Lagrange equation for this functional?

Comment: Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3005/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic thank you vm.

Comment: Hint: if you use $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_nu A_\mu$, you can obtain $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=j^\nu$, which is two of the equations. The others follow trivially from writing $E,\,B$ in terms of $A^\mu$; in covariant terms, they are the tautology $\partial_{(\mu}F_{\nu\rho)}=0$, not an Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: @J.G. thank you. Is this the argument that there is no preferred coordinate axis for $\phi$ or $\vec A$, since an observer measuring $[A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3]$ would see $A_0$ as the electric potential, while another observer measuring in another ("wrongly tilted") way might measure $[A_1, A_2, A_3, A_0]$ or $[A_2, A_3, A_0, A_1]$, thus there is no intrinsic difference between measured $\vec E$ and $\vec B$?

Comment: It was more that $E^i=F^{0i},\,B^i=\frac12\epsilon^i{}_{jk}F^{jk}$ reduces $\nabla\cdot B=0,\,\nabla\times E+\dot{B}$ to the commuting of partial derivatives.

Answer (score -1):

The Euler-Lagrange condition splits into n independent simultaneous equations per each field component.

$$d_t(\frac{dL}{dA_{0,t}})+d_x(\frac{dL}{dA_{0,x}})+d_y(\frac{dL}{dA_{0,y}})+d_z(\frac{dL}{dA_{0,z}}) - \frac{dL}{dA_0}=0\\
d_t(\frac{dL}{dA_{1,t}})+d_x(\frac{dL}{dA_{1,x}})+d_y(\frac{dL}{dA_{1,y}})+d_z(\frac{dL}{dA_{1,z}})- \frac{dL}{dA_1}=0\\
d_t(\frac{dL}{dA_{2,t}})+d_x(\frac{dL}{dA_{2,x}})+d_y(\frac{dL}{dA_{2,y}})+d_z(\frac{dL}{dA_{2,z}})- \frac{dL}{dA_2}=0\\d_t(\frac{dL}{dA_{3,t}})+d_x(\frac{dL}{dA_{3,x}})+d_y(\frac{dL}{dA_{3,y}})+d_z(\frac{dL}{dA_{3,z}})- \frac{dL}{dA_3}=0\\$$

For L defined as

$$L=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} $$
$$= \frac{1}{2}[(E_x)^2+(E_y)^2+(E_z)^2-(B_x)^2-(B_y)^2-(B_x)^2]$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}[(\frac{dA_0}{dx})^2+(\frac{dA_0}{dy})^2+(\frac{dA_0}{dz})^2 -(\frac{dA_3}{dy}-\frac{dA_2}{dz})^2 - (\frac{dA_1}{dz} - \frac{dA_3}{dx})^2 - (\frac{dA_2}{dx} - \frac{dA_1}{dy})^2]\\$$

E-L equation 1 gives:

$$d_t(0) + d_x(\frac{dA_0}{dx}) + d_y(\frac{dA_0}{dy}) 
+ d_z(\frac{dA_0}{dz}) - (0)= 0\\
\frac{dE_x}{dx} + \frac{dE_y}{dy} + \frac{dE_z}{dz} = 0\\
\color{red}{\nabla \cdot \vec E = 0}\\$$

which is Maxwell's 1st equation in free space.

E-L equation 2 gives:

$$d_t(0) + d_x(0) + d_y(\frac{dA_2}{dx} -\frac{dA_1}{dy}) + d_z(\frac{dA_3}{dx} - \frac{dA_1}{dz}) - (0)= 0\\
\frac{dB_z}{dy} - \frac {dB_y}{dz} = 0\\$$

E-L equation 3 gives:
$$\frac{dB_x}{dz} - \frac {dB_z}{dx} = 0\\$$

E-L equation 4 gives:
$$\frac{dB_y}{dx} - \frac {dB_x}{dy} = 0\\$$

which three together gives

$$\color{red}{\nabla \times \vec B = 0}$$

which is Maxwell 4th equation for when $\vec j=0$ and $\frac{d \vec E}{dt} = 0$.

---

Charge source density $\rho$ and charge movement $\vec j$ enters via

$$L_{QED}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + i\bar \Psi \gamma^\mu\frac{d\Psi}{d\mu}- m\bar \Psi \Psi - q_e\bar \Psi\gamma^\mu A_\mu\Psi$$

in which case

$$\frac{dL}{dA_\mu} = q_e\bar \Psi\gamma^\mu \Psi$$

and

$$\color{red}{\nabla \cdot \vec E = q_e\bar \Psi\gamma^0 \Psi}\\$$
$$\color{red}{\nabla \times \vec B = \begin{pmatrix} q_e\bar \Psi\gamma^1 \Psi \\ q_e\bar \Psi\gamma^2 \Psi \\ q_e\bar \Psi\gamma^3 \Psi\end{pmatrix}}$$